# Events in MobX: call method of view from action of store

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

How I call method of view from async action of store in MobX? For example, I have code, like this:

```
@action
someAction() {
  longOperation()
    .then(() => { })
    .catch(error => { });
}
```

When the function is successful or failed, some method in view should be called, for example, show error dialog or call `push` method on `Navigator`.

Currently, I have idea: create an observable field in store with status. When status will change, `render` method of my view will call and I will can handle occurred action and reset status in store.

But is there any better variants of implementation of this idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [**return the promise from the action and just do what you want once it has resolved**](http://jsbin.com/tirihizuvo/1/edit?js,output).

**Example**

```
function longOperation() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
}

class Store {
  @observable data = 'foo';
  @action
  someAction() {
    return longOperation()
      .then(() => this.data = 'bar')
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
}

const store = new Store();

@observer
class App extends React.Component {
  @observable stuff = 'test';
  onClick = () => {
    store.someAction().then(() => this.stuff += '!');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        {`${this.stuff} ${store.data}`}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```